# How can I set text of an item in QTableWidget centered both horizontally and vertically in pyqt?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am currently working with pyqt and have a table. In this table I want to center all the items both horizontally and vertically.

My code is:

```
for row_index in range(9):
    for column_index in range(9):
        item = self.ui.sudoku.item(row_index, column_index)
        item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
```

I tried adding the line to center it vertically:
for row_index in range(9):

```
for row_index in range(9):
    for column_index in range(9):
        item = self.ui.sudoku.item(row_index, column_index)
        item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
```

But now the text only aligns centered only vertically. 
How can I make the text align centered in both dimensions?

Comment: I think you're looking for [`QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#AlignmentFlag-enum).

Comment: use `item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)` or `item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)`